# What is the logic behind this trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to verify this identity

$\sin^2 x \tan x = \tan x - \cos x \sin x$

Here is the correct answer

$\sin^2 x \tan x = (\sin^3/\cos x) = (\sin x/\cos x) - \cos x \sin x = \tan x - \cos x \sin x$

What is the logic behind:

$(\sin^3/\cos x) = (\sin x/\cos x) - \cos x \sin x $

How does $\cos x \sin x $ end up being subtracted from $(\sin x/\cos x)$?

Comment: That step uses $\sin^3 x = (\sin x )(\sin^2 x) =( \sin x) (1-\cos^2 x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the answer you're looking at has failed at is being transparent. Recall the Pythagorean identity for trigonometry: $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. This gives the equivalent form $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$ which is obtained just by subtracting $\cos^2\theta$ from both sides. Now... \begin{align*}(\sin^2\theta)(\tan\theta)&=(1-\cos^2\theta)(\tan\theta)\\ &=\tan\theta-\cos^2\theta\tan\theta\\ &=\tan\theta-\cos^2\theta\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\ &=\tan\theta-\cos\theta\sin\theta.\end{align*}

In the answer that you're looking at, they're using the fact that $\sin^3\theta=(\sin^2\theta)(\sin\theta)=(1-\cos^2\theta)(\sin\theta)$. At this point, you can distribute the $\sin\theta$ and split up the fraction based on the subtraction in the numerator to follow their work.

Comment: So all of that is occurring over $\cos x$?

Comment: @MichaelFox: The first bit that I gave could be considered a complete solution. In the second paragraph, I explain that in the answer you're looking at, you have $(\sin^3\theta)/\cos\theta$. Doing some manipulations with $\sin^3\theta$ and then expanding again gets the same answer as what I posted above. Does this make more sense?

Comment: If you use that logic in your second paragraph and apply it to $(\sin^3/\cos \theta)$, wouldn't the ultimate transformation have to be $(\sin x - \sin x \cos^2 \theta)/\cos \theta$ if you were to distribute $(\sin \theta)$ into $(1 - \cos^2 \theta)$?

Comment: OKAY, I got it.  Thank you!  I had to reduce, der.